# Overriding styles without !important

Tags: css

How is it possible to override styles specified in another style sheet?

I do not want to use the `!important` tag to override them. I would much rather specify a new style sheet, put styles in there. Could this be achieved by changing the load order of the style sheets?

Comment: Why was the twitter-boostrap tag removed? I see it as relevant to this question.

Comment: @AndresIlich, The `another style sheet` does not necessarily have to be `twitter-bootstrap`.

Comment: @Starx i understand but the initial question referred to that framework, isn't it relevant to the posters case?

Comment: @AndresIlich, Localised version of question are not regarded as priority, since SO is focused on helping the community rather than a single asker.

Comment: @Starx i understand that but there is a [twitter bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag for a reason, but i guess using this format the question supplies for a multitude of questions, just not the one relevant to the poster case.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It depends. CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets, and there's a specific order that styles are applied in, overwriting previous styles. Without going into too much detail:

- If your rules have the same specificity, just load your stylesheet second and everything will work fine.
- If your rules have higher specificity, the order won't matter.
- If your rules have lower specificity, you'll need to modify them to match.

So, what's specificity? Basically, it's the sum of each selector in a rule. So this:

```css
a {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Has less specificity than this:

```css
body a {
    color: orange;
}
```

ID selectors have higher specificity than class selectors, which have the same specificity as pseudo-class selectors, which have higher specificity than tag selectors. So if all your content is contained in a `<div>` with an `id` of `content`, you would be able to override a style that looks like this:

```css
body a {
    border: 0;
}
```

With:

```css
#content a {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: But I was told styling using ID selectors is bad practice.  ID selectors should only be used for JS?

Comment: @Matthew: You were told wrongly. Of course, if it’s your preference, feel free to not use id selectors; this answer states facts about precedence and doesn’t make any recommendation.

Comment: @minitech Ahh, I see.  The good thing about classes is that they give you more flexibility.  You can add multiple classes to an element, unlike with ID selectors.  Which makes sense.

Comment: @Matthew: You don’t have to use ids *or* classes on something. You can use both. Use each as appropriate – namely, classes for classes/categories/types of UI elements, and ids as unique identifiers…

Comment: @RyanO'Hara CSSLint throws warnings every time IDs are used in the selector. That's what gave *me* the impression that they were bad. It's not really an authoritative source, though. That's a very good point.

Comment: @LukeTaylor: Yep, CSSLint is frankly wrong. Just because classes are useful much more often than ids doesn’t mean it’s useful to warn on every single instance of an id. That hides the real problems.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Yeah, that's what I suspected. I've switched to stylelint now. CSSLint was too specific about how I had to lay out my whole codebase.

Answer (score 2):

The boostrap stylesheet should be loaded first, your stylesheet second, this way your overwrites will be picked up.

This is called "cascading", from the documentation:

> **Cascading**
>       This is the capability provided by some style sheet languages such as CSS to allow style information from several sources to be blended
>   together. These could be, for instance, corporate style guidelines,
>   styles common to a group of documents, and styles specific to a single
>   document. By storing these separately, style sheets can be reused,
>   simplifying authoring and making more effective use of network
>   caching. **The cascade defines an ordered sequence of style sheets where
>   rules in later sheets have greater precedence than earlier ones.** Not
>   all style sheet languages support cascading.

Answer (score 2):

look at http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html.

```
<p class="example">
    This is a <strong>test</strong>.
</p>

strong { color: red; }
p strong { color: green; }
p.example strong { color: blue; }
```

The text will be blue. The order of the rules doesn't matter.

Comment: but it is a good link that explaines the specificity on the basis of star wars :)

Comment: It's better if you example about the power what OP asking about then give a link as an reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you can increase the [specificity of styles](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html), you can do this without the `!important`.

For example:

HTML

```
<div id="selector">
  <a>Hello</a>
  <a class="specific">Hi</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
div a {}
```

Will be ignored, if you give a specific class inside `#selector`

```css
.specific { }
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/PnvTJ/) explaining my point. Basically, the idea is to define the styles as closely as possible.