# How to override default css style rule of Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have following default style applied to my form label:

```
  @media (min-width: 1200px)
   .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
    }
```

So how can I override it by making {float:none;}? If I write a new class, still it's not taking it up.

I tried: in custom.css:

```
  @media (min-width: 1200px){.form-label-float{float:none;}}
```

It did not work!

html:

order of css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="../css/bootswatch.less"/>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="../css/variables.less"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/custom.css"/>

 <div id="passCode"></div>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
    <legend style="color:#145FAC">Please Fill in the Online Form</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control formWidth" id="inputName" placeholder="Nam" />
        </div>...</div>
</fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: can you show the HTML you want to apply this to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check selector specificity values - try to add !important - if it works than try to calculate yours and bootstrap's selector specificity and compare it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

[image]

Comment: I added important, it did not work. All label moved to right of form text input field, though it's applied.

Comment: can you check is the style applied to the element in devTools (chrome)? Is this style active or overrided by something else?

Comment: style float:none is active.

Comment: If this style is not striked out in the dev tools it means it affects the element. 

So if this style is active maybe it's just not behave as you'd expect it to?

Comment: you have a screenshot attached within my answer how it should / should not look like

Answer (score 0):

Here are some best practices to follow :

- Always load **custom.css** or **style.css** after base css file (not responsive).
- Avoid using **!important** if possible. That can override some important
  stylings from base.
- Always load bootstrap-responsive.css after custom.css if you don't
  want to lose media queries.. - **MUST FOLLOW**
- Prefer modifying required properties (not all)...

If you load your custom css file before bootstrap.css file then it will override your custom style.

I hope you've got the answer by now..

We in our organization follow these best practices to achieve best customization..

Answer (score 0):

If your `float:none` active but the element is showing right or left side you use `display:block` or `display:table` . I think this link can help you to rewrite default bootstrap css 
https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Try using higher specificity. For your HTML above, you can do

```
select col-lg-2, select col-lg-10{
    float:none;
}
```

This will override the bootstrap styles because it has a higher specificity.

See [Overriding styles without !important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956467/overriding-styles-without-important)

Comment: Thanks! Since all of you have answered right, I had choose first come first