# How to avoid using the CSS !important Rule here in my code?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, emotion-js

I am trying to give color on hover to the anchor tag it is not working, When I give **!important** then the style gets applied. I am using **emotion JS** where I am exporting the file and importing that style in the component, The solution I need is to apply the color without using **!important**.

Here is the code:

```
import { css } from '@emotion/react';

const ErrorStyles = css({
  color: '#c34922',
  textDecorationColor: '#c34922',
  '&:hover': {
    color: '#c34922 !important',
    textDecorationColor: '#c34922 !important',
  },
});

export {ErrorStyles };
```

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import {ErrorStyles} from './ErrorScreenStyles';

const ErrorScreen=()=>{
return(
<>
 <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" css={ErrorStyles}>
  Create an account.
 </a>
</>
)
}
export default ErrorScreen;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding styles without !important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956467/overriding-styles-without-important)

Comment: Why you are using the same colour on the original state and the hover state?

Comment: because on hover also we need same color

Comment: Use your browser dev tools, and figure out where the current color applied in the hover state comes from. Must be something with higher specificity.